# C++ passing data from object of class A to object of derived class B

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

For the sample code below, I'm trying to pass (or attribute, if that suits you better) the data from object of class `A` to the object of derived class `B`. What I don't understand so far, is how do I transfer the data from the parent class object, to the derived class object.

The "code" below expresses how I've tried to do that.

```
class Foo {
protected:
    string Name, Surname;

public:
    void readData()
    {
        cin >> Name >> Surname >> ;
    }
}

class Bar : public Foo {
public:
    Bar(Foo a)
    {
        Name = Name;
        Surname = Surname;
    }
    void printData()
    {
        //code
    }
}

int
main()
{
    Foo a;
    a.readData();
    Bar b(a);
    b.printData()
}
```

Comment: `Name = Name;` is "noop", did you mean `Name = a.Name;`?

Comment: and better `Bar (Foo a) : Foo(std::move(a)) {}`.

Comment: Hey @Jarod42, why not go all the way to `Bar (const Foo &a) : Foo(a) {}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 i've tried with a.Name, but it is saying to me that ` it not accesible through a "A" pointer or object

Comment: @ypnos: Possible, does extra copies in some case though (instead of extra move in all cases) (there are also trade-off between providing one good enough overload, or several overloads).

Comment: @dapet: `protected` access can only be used through the derived class. So `a.Name` is not possible, whereas `/*this->*/Name` is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minimal changes to make your code compile is using `Foo`s copy constructor and simply access the inherited members in `Bar::printData`:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
 protected:
 std::string Name, Surname;
 public:
 void readData()
 {
  std::cin >> Name >> Surname;
 } 
 };

class Bar : public Foo
{
 public:
 Bar (const Foo& a) : Foo(a) {  }
 void printData()
 {
    std::cout << Name << " " << Surname;
 }
};

int main()
{
 Foo a;
 a.readData();
 Bar b(a);
 b.printData();
}
```

Comment: Well, the reason I wrote it how I wrote it, is because of my assignment, to be more concrete, I have to work with my `main` as is, but thank you for your help! It really helped!

Comment: @dapet when there are such requirements you should mention them in the question. Anyhow, imho the assignment is a little silly. I hope it is just a step towards the full picture. Perhaps the aim was to illustrate one aspect (`protected`?), and without knowing what that was it is no surprise that it looks a little silly

Comment: this assignment was related to the topic we just passed in our course, called Inheritance and the `code` that I've wrote below doesn't represent the whole assignment, but only the part that I've struggled with